# Rails unable to mass assign values to DB when delegation to getter/setter is used

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app- I have 2 models, `User` and `Post`. A user has one post. I have a has_one to belongs relationship.

In my user controller, I update attributes of the post (say `post_text`) by calling `user.update_attributes!(params[:post])`

In the User model, I have 
`attr_accessible :post_text` (The view accepts a `post_text`) which I can see being passed to the controller.

Also, I delegate the setter methods on

```
delegate :post_text, 'post_text=', :post_text?, to: :post
```

In Post class, I have implemented the above 3 methods eg -

```
def post_text=(input_text)
  #logic
end
def post_text
  #logic
end

def post_text?
  #logic
end
```

When I try to persist the input from form, it does not get saved to the DB i.e. DB is always empty. I have tried debugging in the form of unit and controller level tests and they all work as expected. How can I go about debugging further?

Comment: What are you trying to do? sounds like a really complicated way to update a post, I think you are trying to solve a problem with the wrong approach, please explain the use case of this (maybe you need to use accept_nested_attributes_for or just update the desired Post record)

Comment: You're right. I am working on a legacy codebase and I was trying to explain the code, though I did not use the exact Models, business logic :)

Comment: I don't know the use case, but I think the syntax should be `delegate :post_text, 'post_text=', :post_text?, to: :post`, but I'm not sure if that should even work as you except it

Comment: That's exactly what I did. However, I realized that doing `update_attributes!` on the User method (I pass in the post attributes) gives me `Can't mass assign protected attributes` It's almost like Rails does not recognize the getter and setter being delegated...

Answer (score 0):

models/user.rb

```
has_many :posts
```

models/post.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

For more information [Active Record Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Sorry, this was not helpful. i already mentioned that the association is available.